# force browser scale to with fixed aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is there any possibility to force, if the user is scaling the browser window, to have a fixed aspect ratio. for example

```
$('window').on('resize', ... fixed aspect ratio)
```

or is this impossible?

Comment: You probably can (at least in some situations; almost certainly not the window your main page was initially loaded in). It **will** piss off your users.

Comment: What is it about your design that requires a specific aspect-ratio?

Comment: People using Windows 8 and various tablet/phone devices generally don't have much choice as to aspect ratio.

Comment: Do you mean locking the aspect ratio of the browser window or of HTML elements that are currently scaling with the browser?

Comment: well im using kind of parallax scrolling effect with lots of divs, one below the other and im using css3's cover (width 100%) to fill the complete browser window. if the browser doesnt have the aspect ratio of the bg-images are gaps between them! and thats what i want to prevent. maybe theres another solution... you get my point? thanks

Comment: I think it's better to solve the problem with the gaps. Open a new question for that with relevant parts of your code/css.

Answer (score 0):

window.resizeTo(w,h) is what you should be looking for. BUT this does not work in Firefox and Chrome as of now for windows that were not opened using window.open. Surprisingly enough IE 10 still allows this method to run on it's base window.

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.resizeTo